# How to access Jenkins container deployed in OpenShift (AWS) from outside

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, openshift

I deployed the OpenShift container platform on AWS using Cloud formation template. It created 3 EC2 instances with 1 master node and 2 worker nodes. Then I created a project named `cicd` and created Jenkins container inside of it and added an external route as shown below.

[image: Open Shift Origin Console]

When I try to access the Jenkins console https://jenkins-cicd.router.default.svc.cluster.local/ I get **This site can’t be reached** error. Adding `Allow All` Inbound rule to Security group did not fix the issue.

[image: Inbound Firewall rules]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you left DNS configuration in CloudFormation. You will need to provide DNS information here properly. So that Ansible will configure OpenShift to use the right domain name. The load balancer will be configured based on that too.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this screen? I couldn't find it when setting up CloudFormation stack

Comment: Please use the link https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/openshift/. Goto "How to Deploy" > Depoy into a new VPC. You should see that option.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Actually, we are trying to deploy OKD on AWS with this [template](https://github.com/pavankjadda/BookStore/wiki/CloudFormationTemplateOpenShift.yaml). So, I may need to modify the DNS settings on my account

Comment: You will need to configure it in your playbook with the right subdomain. It's the same for master & apps load balancers.

openshift_master_default_subdomain=apps.domain.com
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=master.domain.com

Make sure that your Route53 records pointing to the classic load balancers right.

*.apps.domain.com > Infra Classic Load Balancer
master.domain.com > Master Classic Load balancer.